# iTC Mobile stopped working normally a couple of days ago

Tags: iphone, mobile, itunes, app-store-connect

The iTC Mobile (iTunes Connect Mobile) app stopped working normally on my iPod touch. A few weeks ago it started showing "Incomplete or malformed request" when I tap on Products tab, now it shows "Error 76. iTC Mobile could not connect to the iTunes Connect service. Please try again later." right after login. This is happening the 2nd or 3rd day.

The device is connected to Internet; the app still works fine on Markets, Search and Settings tabs. I have the latest version of the app, 1.2. Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Comment: I'd had the same issue, it dissapeared a week ago. Now it does not send any push notification about apps status.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove it, and re-install?